# Split data into new column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013

As per attachment i have column A having name with underscore "_' and bracket " [ " . I need a formula to get answer of column  B means I need formula to get id before underscore and inside bracket .

now am doing by Data--> Text to Column , feel its not a good way because A column is splitting into 2 .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hx6Nr.jpg)
Hoping anyone can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the underscore it's: `=LEFT(A1;FIND("_";A1)-1)`

For the bracket it's: `=MID(A1;FIND("[";A1)+1;FIND("]";A1)-FIND("[";A1)-1)`

The above formulas check the value in cell A1. You need to evaluate which formula to use. But the evaluation depends on "all" the datasets. For example if there is never brackets and underscore together and there is an underscore or a bracket in every value it's easy (just use an if formula that uses the first formula if it finds an underscore and the second formular in all other cases) if not it gets more complicated. Then you need to write more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("_",A1))=FALSE,LEFT(A1,FIND("_",A1)-1),(IF(ISERROR(FIND("-",A1))=FALSE,LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1),(IF(ISERROR(FIND("[",A1))=FALSE,MID(A1,FIND("[",A1)+1,FIND("]",A1)-FIND("[",A1)-1))))))
```

[image]