# Excel Formula output error

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013

As per below previous question link please find attached , formula is not giving output properly as if i need number inside the bracket only, hope any one can help [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1au7v.jpg)

[Split data into new column](https://superuser.com/q/1341535/715257)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your text is in `A1`, you can use `MID()` with `SEARCH()`:

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH("[",A1)+1,SEARCH("]",A1)-SEARCH("[",A1)-1)
```